# What does the tailwindcss CLI build process command do?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css for my project, and I was able to get it to work using only the first 3 steps listed on their [installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) page. The next step has a command to start the CLI build process:

`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

What does this command do? How was I able to use tailwind without running it? Will I run into problems down the line if I skip it?

Comment: You should accept the answer so he gets credit for it. I had the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this command do?

It takes the file `./src/input.css`, processes it through Tailwind to build CSS rules and the outputs it to `./dist/output.css`. `--watch` keeps the process running to watch for relevant file changes and recompiles to `./dist/output.css`.

> How was I able to use tailwind without running it?

Your project may have some existing build process that can automatically run Tailwind if it is installed in the project.

> Will I run into problems down the line if I skip it?

This is difficult to tell due to withheld information.